# Regenerating images after new image style

Tags: 7, media

I created a new image style. When I inspect my code, the image style has been applied but it doesn't find the image. The image and the new folder in `sites/default/files/styles` hasn't been created?

Whats wrong, how do I generate my new image(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal creates derivatives images "on the fly" based on a defined image style. The act of creating a new style does not generate any images. Rather, the first time an image is requested using that style it will be generated and saved in `sites/default/files/styles/{stylename}/path/to/image.jpg`.

If you (for example) create a view that displays nodes with images using your newly defined image style, then as soon as you go to a page with that view the images will be generated.

Comment: thanks but when I visit the page and I inspect the code I see the new image style name in the path `sites/default/files/styles/{stylename}/public/myImage`. When I look in the console (developer tools) I see a 403 (Forbidden) error on the image?

Comment: that sounds like a file permission problem, not an image style problem. Can you ssh into your server and run `ls -la sites/default/files/styles/{stylename}/public/myImage` and see what your permissions situation is.

Comment: I can't do above because Drupal didn't generate the image (and folder) yet... If I run `ls -la sites/default/files/styles/`, I get `drwxr-xr-x@` for the `/style/` folder.

Comment: who owns that folder? What user and what group? Then, figure out what user/group your running your web server as and you will see that something is amiss somewhere. You will either need to change the permissions on your files folder (or styles folder) OR you will need to change the user/group that your webserver is running as